# Single photon Rabi frequency for Exciton Photon in 2D potential well with microcavity

Tags: dipole, bose-einstein-condensate, cavity-qed, laser-cavity, rabi-model

I was just going through an article on Exciton-polariton Condensate in 2D and in the photon-exciton interaction strength (single photon Rabi frequency) inside a cavity seems to have a term of Bohr radius of exciton,
g = (d/2*pi *a_B )Sqrt(E_cavity/2E*E_o*L_c). Since the laser beam is incident over a region of 30 micrometers, but it is taking the effective area to be Bohr radius(a_B, whose dimension is 5 nm). So, I couldn't understand how this oscillation in terms of area of exciton instead of area over which beam was incident ? Any helpsare appreciated. Thanks in advance.[image]

Above the Energy of the exciton and photon as well as their interaction strength and jaynes cumming hamiltonian. The images below are from J. Kasprzak et al., Nature 443, 409 (2006) paper https://www.nature.com/articles/nature05131.

Comment: Would you cite the article? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the post with the relevant links.

Comment: The article you cited only contains half of the above diagram: the formulas in the diagram do not appear in the text, neither do the authors mention the word bohr radius.... (at least I can't find it by searching in the published Nature article). So where did you find all the bohr stuff?